# Can anyone please help fix the following glmmLasso R package errors?

Tags: r, lasso-regression

I have been trying to run the following code and I am getting various errors. Anyone know how to fix the current one? I am trying to run a generalized linear mixed model with a tuning parameter (specifically LASSO), but was trying to start at the basics and get the fixed effects to work first. Thank you!

```
y <- rbinom(n = 50, size = 1, prob = .5)
x <- rnorm(n = 50, mean = 1, sd = .5)

data <- data.frame(x, y)

mod1 <- glmmLasso(fix = y ~ x , rnd = NULL, family = binomial(link = logit), lambda = 10, data = data)
```

error: the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be usedthe condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

another error: data length is not a multiple of split variable (this does not happen with this simulation data, but it does with my real data)

Another note - I have tried the exact code in the help documentation for generalized linear mixed models with the soccer data and I get the same error about the length > 1

Comment: does this work? `binomial(link = "logit")`

Comment: no :( it gives the same error

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is a problem with R 4.0.3.
I used glmmLasso without any errors and this error occurred when I updated my Base R from 3.6 to 4.0.3. I wrote an email to the author.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that with only 1 predictor and data that has no relationship, your lambda is too high for 1 variable and throws a weird solution of the matrix, you can check see the [source code](https://rdrr.io/cran/glmmLasso/src/R/glmm_final_noRE.R) throws error at these two lines:

```
finish<-(sqrt(sum((Eta.ma[l,]-Eta.ma[l+1,])^2))/sqrt(sum((Eta.ma[l,])^2))<eps)
finish2<-(sqrt(sum((Eta.ma[l-1,]-Eta.ma[l+1,])^2))/sqrt(sum((Eta.ma[l-1,])^2))<eps)

if(finish ||  finish2)
```

To make this reproducible:

```
set.seed(2)

y <- rbinom(n = 50, size = 1, prob = .5)
x <- rnorm(n = 50, mean = 1, sd = .5)

data <- data.frame(x, y)

mod1 <- glmmLasso(fix = y ~ x , rnd = NULL, family = binomial(link = logit), lambda = 10, data = data)

Error in if (finish || finish2) break : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

mod1 <- glmmLasso(fix = y ~ x , rnd = NULL, family = binomial(link = logit), lambda = 1, data = data)

mod1
Call:
glmmLasso(fix = y ~ x, rnd = NULL, data = data, lambda = 1, family = binomial(link = logit))

Fixed Effects:

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           x 
 -0.8089034   0.8678967
```

If we try another seed, you can see there's no issue, although you can see the end solution is a the coefficient set to zero:

```
set.seed(1)
y <- rbinom(n = 50, size = 1, prob = .5)
x <- rnorm(n = 50, mean = 1, sd = .5)
data <- data.frame(x, y)
    
mod1 <- glmmLasso(fix = y ~ x , rnd = NULL, family = binomial(link = logit), lambda = 10, data = data)

mod1
Call:
glmmLasso(fix = y ~ x, rnd = NULL, data = data, lambda = 10, 
    family = binomial(link = logit))

Fixed Effects:

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           x 
  0.1603426   0.0000000
```

To sum up.. most likely for your data, you need to move it through some lambdas to examine the fit

Comment: hmm I have tried to move through some lambdas and still not having any luck. The code I presented is to mimic real data that I have that has more predictors. We wanted to see if we could get it to work with fake data, but we were getting the same error.

Comment: can you set lambda to a very low value, like 0.0001?

Comment: That did not work either for the simulation data, my real data, or the glmmLasso example data. I still get this error: the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be usedthe condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used . Could it be something with software or settings that is causing this? When I copy and pasted your exact code, I still get the same error.

Comment: there's something weird.. either you have packages that clash with glmmLasso or yeah you might need to reinstall it.. i am on R3.6 though .. are you on R 4.0 ?

Comment: Good to know, I have never heard of packages clashing. I will look into that. I am using R version 4.0.3 and R Studio 1.3.1093. I appreciate your help!